# angular 2 http service can't parse json from dotnet

Tags: angular

I am so much confused with angular 2 http service.

I have a very simple model on asp.net:

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Answer> Answers {get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    ...
}
```

and responce with object of this model is looking like this:

```
[{"questionId":0,"value":"qqq","answers":
[{"answerId":25,"value":"qwerty"}]},
{"questionId":1,"value":"eee","answers":
[{"answerId":26,"value":"qwerty2"}]}]
```

So, I've looked on this json and copied this model to typescript classes:

```
export class Question {
    questionId: number;
    value: string;
    answers: Array<Answer>;
} 

export class Answer {
    answerId: number;
    value: string;
}
```

Then I wrote httpservice:

```
GetQuestions(): Observable<Question[]> {
    return this.http.get("Api/GetAllQuestions")
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();  
    return body || {};
}
```

I tried to use it:

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.questionService.GetQuestions()
         .subscribe(
         questions => this.questions = questions,
         error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

And looks like my questions array is somehow initialized after this method executed. Stringify of questions array is looking like that:

```
[{"questionId":0,"value":"qqq","answers":
[{"answerId":25,"value":"qwerty"}]},
{"questionId":1,"value":"eee","answers":
{"answerId":26,"value":"qwerty2"}]}]
```

But if I try to use it

```
 <div class="panel panel-default" *ngFor="let q of questions">
    <label>
        id: {{q.questionId}} val: {{value}}
    </label>
    <div *ngFor="let a of q.answers">
        <label>
               id: {{a.answerId}} value: {{a.value}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

- I see nothing! Besides, `questuin.length` is 2 (expected), but `questions[0].questionId` is giving me nothing. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Javascript is a case-sensitive language. Try to use `q.questionId` `q.value` `q.answers` etc

Comment: You also have to be aware that the parsed json will be plain Objects, the TypeScript class information will not be in there. You will have to make use of some conversion library to get the type information back in the data.

Comment: Dotnet by default serializers json uppercase as `[{"QuestionId":0,"Value":"qqq","Answers" ...}]`. Angular cannot map it into your datatype and may this cause error. Can you check it?